# Android Programming: Dragging a button

Tags: java, android, button, slide, drag

I am using a onTouch listener to implement a draggable button. Here is my code:

```
final Button b = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setFocusable(false);
    b.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        int k = 0; 
        int prevX;
        int x = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent e) {
            final LinearLayout.LayoutParams par = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();

            switch (e.getAction()) {
                case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE):
                    if (k == 0) {
                        prevX = (int) e.getRawX();
                    }

                    x += (int) e.getRawX() - prevX;
                    prevX = (int) e.getRawX();
                    par.leftMargin = x;

                    Log.d("jy", "x: " + x);

                    k++;

                    v.setLayoutParams(par);
                    return true;
                case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
                    b.setText("hi");
                    par.bottomMargin = 0;
                    par.leftMargin = 0;
                    k = 0;
                    x = 0;
                    v.setLayoutParams(par);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
```

I can drag the button only for a little bit though. Once I drag past the original location of the button, the onTouchListener stops working.

Note: this is a button inside a custom list row cell. I am using a linearlayout.

Comment: It's likely that as you exit the bounds of the control, it stops receiving touch events. Why don't you use an `OnDragListener` instead?

Comment: I tried using an OnDragListener, but it doesn't even register the initial drag.

Comment: Did you follow all the steps from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html ?